# Warning: Wunused-but-set-variable

Tags: c++, unused-variables

I receive this warning when compiling my program.

```
In member function 'bool CClientManager::InitializeMobTable()':
warning: variable 'isNameFile' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
bool isNameFile = true;
     ^
```

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
bool CClientManager::InitializeMobTable()
{
        map<int,const char*> localMap;
        bool isNameFile = true;


        cCsvTable nameData;
        if(!nameData.Load("mob_names.txt",'\t'))
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "mob_names.txt 파일을 읽어오지 못했습니다\n");
                isNameFile = false;
        } else {
                nameData.Next();
                while(nameData.Next()) {
                        localMap[atoi(nameData.AsStringByIndex(0))] = nameData.AsStringByIndex(1);
                }
        }
        // More ...
 }
```

I put the rest on pastebin because is too big: http://pastebin.com/HrVLimgn

The warninig is on 170 Line in that file on pastebin.

My question is, how can I fix?
 If you comment these lines with a bit affects my program?

Comment: You need to reduce the code to a minimal example and include it in your post.

Comment: The warning is quite clear: if the variable is never used, do you think it would affect the program?

Answer (score 1):

> *"My question is, how can I fix?"*

You can put a

```
(void)isNameFile;
```

statement after the initialization to get rid of the warning, or simply remove the

```
bool isNameFile = true;
```

and

```
isNameFile = false;
```

lines, if the variable isn't used and won't be further (if it's not used because of some temporarily commented code).

> *"If you comment these lines with a bit affects my program?"*

It shouldn't affect your program if you remove or comment that line. The variable isn't used (accessed) other than assigning it elsewhere. That's what the warning says.

Comment: Look at this: http://prntscr.com/7bgbu4  If i comment  bool isNameFile = true;  Then give me error on this  http://prntscr.com/7bgcx4      if i remove that line, then say line 177 is not declared in this scope.

Comment: you can delete both, it is not used thus doesnt change anything in your program, nothing depends on that variable

Comment: @Freaksy The variable is only assigned but never read, that's what the warning says.